# Extract/Refactor/Wrap assert statements into separate function

Tags: python, assert

Does it make sense to wrap assert statements into a separate function? Something like:

```
def main1(x):
    assert 5 <= x <= 10, "value {} not in range [{},{}]".format(x,5,10)
    pass # do something
```

vs

```
def assert_range(x,a,b):
    assert a <= x <= b, "value {} not in range [{},{}]".format(x,a,b)

def main2(x):
    assert_range(x,5,10)
    pass # do something
```

As far as I know assert statements are removed in optimized compilation. What will happen to my `assert_range` function? Will the call to the (now empty) function remain, or is that also optimized away?

Comment: If you would use `assert_range()` more that one time - it make sense.

Comment: @GeorgePetrov: Yes, that's my motivation. But I'm wondering what will happen to that function when the optimization kicks in.

Comment: It then becomes a no-op function (like if the function's body was a mere `pass` statement) - but it will still be called.